# adding subdomain for SharePoint apps

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We have given a DNS entry with SharePoint, now for SharePoint apps it says that we must have sub domain to install apps , so I wish to know where to have this sub domain entry ? should it be the sub domain of  SharePoint web instance in IIS or something to do with Domain controller or DNS server.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we are doing it:

Our organization purchased a domain.  Let's call it "ourapps.com".

We have a dev server to which we are going to deploy our apps for testing. Let's call that server ourdevserver.

We created a DNS entry that resolves any sub domain in the form of *.ourdevserver.ourapps.com"  to the IP address of the dev server.

Remember, when you deploy your apps unique sub domain "app-xxxxxxxx" will be created. So any url in the form of "app-xxxxx.ourdevserver.ourapps.com" will need to find it's way to the IP of the SharePoint server on which the app is hosted.

I hope this helps.

Chris